# ubuntu server 14.04.5 32bit remote gui access

Tags: server

i am running on some old hardware, and i have installed ubuntu server on it.  
because it have a hard time running the gui version, and i wanna know if there is a way to remote gui access without installing and running gui on the physical hardware and taking unnecessary resources ?  
the computer i am using is a hp compaq mini 110c, CPU: atom - N270 1 core 1.6GHz. 
 
running ubuntu 14.04.5 server i386

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not directly an answer to the question:

Depends on what you want to do with this "GUI" I have two suggestions. Anyway AFAIK whatever you want to access has to be installed on that machine somehow...

- For configuration etc you could try [webmin](https://www.webmin.com). This is a webUI for Configuration and maintenance. Therefore you can use it remotely of course.
- Anyway you also could try a lightweight GUI like xfce4. To install it run

  ```
  sudo apt install xfce4
  ```

  this command does only install the basic GUI without additional applications.
  It doesn't use a lot resources and you only start it (by `startx`) when you need it.
  To use this one remotely is a bit more complicated and needs [x forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12755/212783)

On my server's I usually have both.

Comment: xfce4 dont work on my server, sadly

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: long text that it cannot start